# How to compare two column values which are comma separated values?

Tags: sql-server, parsing, csv

I have one table with specific columns, in that there is a column which contains comma separated values like **test,exam,result,other**.

I will pass a string like **result,sample,unknown,extras** as a parameter to the stored procedure. and then I want to get the related records by checking each and every phrase in this string.

For Example:

**TableA**

```
ID        Name                Words
1         samson              test,exam,result,other
2         john                sample,no query
3         smith               tester,SE
```

Now I want to search for **result,sample,unknown,extras**

Then the result should be

```
ID        Name                Words
1         samson              test,exam,result,other
2         john                sample,no query
```

because in the first record **result** matched and in the second record **sample** matched.

Comment: what sql engine you use?

Comment: I would be looking at fixing my database design.

Comment: How do you ask for the people who have 'test,exam,result,other' as exactly the set of results?  That is a sub-optimal design.

Answer (score 7):

That's not a great design, you know. Better to split Words off into a separate table (id, word).

That said, this should do the trick:

```
set nocount on
declare @words varchar(max) = 'result,sample,unknown,extras'

declare @split table (word varchar(64))
declare @word varchar(64), @start int, @end int, @stop int

-- string split in 8 lines
select @words += ',', @start = 1, @stop = len(@words)+1
while @start < @stop begin
  select
    @end   = charindex(',',@words,@start)
  , @word  = rtrim(ltrim(substring(@words,@start,@end-@start)))
  , @start = @end+1
  insert @split values (@word)
end

select * from TableA a
where exists (
  select * from @split w
  where charindex(','+w.word+',',','+a.words+',') > 0
  )
```

May I burn in DBA hell for providing you this!

Edit: replaced STUFF w/ SUBSTRING slicing, an order of magnitude faster on long lists.

Comment: Consider the torch under the bonfire lit, Peter... :D

Comment: Heh. I think it's good you posted this -- serves as a nice illustration of why one shouldn't design things this way.

Comment: I agree that the design could be properly done, but unfortunately some of us can get stuck with these kinds of problems and not have the luxury of being able to alter someone's bad design. Thank you for posting this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think you'd want to look at your application/architecture and think carefully about whether you really want to do this in the database or the application. If it isn't appropriate or not an option then you'll need to create a custom function. The code in the article here should be easy enough to modify to do what you want:

[Quick T-Sql to parse a delimited string](http://codebetter.com/blogs/raymond.lewallen/archive/2005/10/26/133774.aspx) (also look at the code in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have already said -- what you have there is a bad design. Consider using proper relations to represent these things.

That being said, here's a detailed article about how to do this using SQL Server:
http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

One thing no one has covered so far, because it's often a very bad idea -- but then, you are already working with a bad idea, and sometimes two wrongs make a right -- is to extract all rows that match ANY of your strings (using LIKE or some such) and doing the intersection yourself, client-side.  If your strings are fairly rare and highly correlated, this may work pretty well; it will be god-awful in most other cases.