# SQL query string comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I have following two tables i.e. InvoiceData and OrderData
Orders table show what was ordered and invoices show what was delivered along with productID and other information. I want to compare Product id field on both tables by splitting on comma (,) and want to get rows from Invoice data table, even a single product id is available in order's product table.
for e.g. in result i should get invoice#s 123,3334,3456 & 3435.

I have already tried split_String but my env. is sql server 2012 and i got an error.

Could somebody please help me.

Comment: This will be very difficult because your data is not normalized. Is there any way you can normalize the database design?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is a legacy app and has a lot of data already stored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two column values which are comma separated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618387/how-to-compare-two-column-values-which-are-comma-separated-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the way IDs are stored. For this, you will need three more tables.

I suggest reading up on Many to Many relationships (Like between Product -> Invoice, and Product -> Order)

Unnecessary, but I suggest removing 'Data' from the naming convention, as any table in a database is assumed to hold data, it is not helpful in description.

[Product Orders and Invoices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtdMu.png)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I won't be able to invert the IDs storage at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will work as a string split in 2012

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_string_split](@str       NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                                        @delimiter NVARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
     RETURN
     WITH a
          AS (SELECT CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS idx1, 
                     CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @str) idx2
              UNION ALL
              SELECT idx2 + 1, 
                     CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @str, idx2 + 1)
              FROM a
              WHERE idx2 > 0)
          SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, idx1, COALESCE(NULLIF(idx2, 0), LEN(@str) + 1) - idx1) AS value, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                 ORDER BY idx1) RN
          FROM a;
```

You can then use this via a cross apply.

```
DECLARE @Invoices AS TABLE
(InvoiceNumber NVARCHAR(50), 
 ProductIDCSV     NVARCHAR(MAX)
);
INSERT INTO @Invoices
VALUES
('123','Prod123,Prod456,Prod789'),
('456','Prod987,Prod654,Prod321');
SELECT I.*, 
       P.Value AS ProductID
FROM @Invoices I
     CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_string_split(I.ProductIDCSV, ',') P;
```

That will give you a list of Invoice numbers and discrete Product Ids,  you can then perform any comparisons you want.  This should get you on the right path to your answer.

As a side note, it makes life a lot easier for those trying to help you if you provide a dataset that can be cut and pasted, rather than an image.  If you see the second script I've set up a tvp and an insert, thats an easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers.
I finally followed Aaaron's solution at below link.
https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

I had to compare both product IDs's columns using string split. Though it is not a good solution but with such unnormalized data, this seems to be  a working approach.